# Is conversion to multiple anonymous interfaces equivalent to a type switch?

Tags: go, interface, type-conversion, type-switch

I've inherited some code that looks like this:

```
type FooWrapper struct {
    Stuffer   interface{ GetStuff() *grpc.Stuff }
    Thinger   interface{ GetThing() *grpc.Thing }
    Widgeter  interface{ GetWidget() *grpc.Widget }
    // many more like these
}

func NewFooWrapper(v proto.Message) FooWrapper {
    var w FooWrapper
    w.Stuffer, _ = v.(interface{ GetStuff() *grpc.Stuff })
    w.Thinger, _ = v.(interface{ GetThing() *grpc.Thing })
    w.Widgeter, _ = v.(interface{ GetWidget() *grpc.Widget })
    // many more like these
    return w
}

func (w FooWrapper) GetStuff() *grpc.Stuff {
    if w.Stuffer == nil {
        return nil
    }
    return w.Stuffer.GetStuff()
}

// many more methods like this one
```

We can see that this code does the following:

1. It declares a `FooWrapper` struct with a bunch of anonymous interface fields, one for each method that can possibly exist in any implementation of `proto.Message`.
2. The `NewFooWrapper` constructor is converting `v` to each one of those anonymous interface types, discarding the error. Thus, if the type boxed in `v` does not have the `GetXXX` method, the related field in `w` will simply be `nil`
3. `FooWrapper` getters check if the corresponding field is `nil` and if it's not, it invokes the method on the boxed value.

To me this seems a quite verbose way of implementing a type switch, though I'm not sure this is idiomatic Go code.

However I guess it could be useful in cases where `v` had to be passed to multiple unrelated methods, causing the type switch to be copy-pasted everywhere (it's not the case of the code I got here).

Is this code equivalent to a type switch, in practice?

What are the advantages in using this pattern instead of a type switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, "no", it's not idiomatic. But of course that doesn't mean it's "wrong".

Although given that the anonymous interface types are repeated, it seems pretty silly to do that, rather than a named type.

If I had inherited that code, I would immediately change it.

And with that exact code sample in mind, I would also re-define my struct to use embedded interfaces:

```golang
type Stuffer  interface { GetStuff() *grpc.Stuff }
type Thinger  interface { GetThing() *grpc.Thing }
type Widgeter interface { GetWidget() *grpc.Widget }

type FooWrapper struct {
    Stuffer
    Thinger
    Widgeter
    // many more like these
}
```